# client and server example not working

Tags: c++, network-programming, socket.io

i am learning socket programming...i was trying to create a program in which i enter a sentence on the client screen and it is transmitted to the server and then it appears on the terminal on which the server is running....the codes are [here](http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=zszjX).....(after seeing the first answer to this question i realised my mistake and changed **sockfd1 in read() function to connfd** and used **fork() after accept()** in server.cpp...but still prog doesn't work )

earlier in client.cpp, i had used fgets(clibuff, 100, stdin) and had put this and write(sockcli, clibuff, strlen(clibuff)) in an infinite for loop but that didn't work...

so i decided to make it work for just one statement and removed the for loop....but this too doesn't work...

when i run these on two separate command lines they both start fine(since the x from both the programs output 0)...but ***when i type anything on client side and press enter...it doesn't appear on server window***... The relevant parts of code are:

```
-------server.cpp-----

int sockfd1;
sockfd1=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
int x=bind(sockfd1, (sockaddr*)(&serv), sizeof(serv)); //serv is my sockaddr_in structure
cout<<x<<endl;
listen(sockfd1,5);

listen(sockfd1,5);
int y;
for(;;)
{
connfd=accept(sockfd1, &cliaddr, &siz);     

if((y=read(sockfd1, servbuff, 100))>0) //i changed sockfd1 here to connfd
fputs(servbuff, stdout);

}



-----client.cpp------

char clibuff[100];
char line[100];

sockaddr_in cli;
bzero(&cli, sizeof(cli));
cli.sin_family=AF_INET;
inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &(cli.sin_addr));
cli.sin_port=htons(2289);

int sockcli;
sockcli=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
int x= connect(sockcli,(sockaddr*)&cli, sizeof(cli));
cout<<x<<endl;

cin>>clibuff;
write(sockcli, clibuff, strlen(clibuff));

return 0;
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code inline in your question. Without that, as soon as that link goes dead, your question has 0 value for anyone.

Comment: @Mat + 1 'cos I appended your comment to mine to try and get it to happen.

Comment: add fflush(stdout); after fputs() to it

Answer (score 2):

You are reading from the listening socket.  You should not be doing that.

'connfd' is the server<>client socket for the newly-connected client - it is the socket on which you should be reading/writing fo that client.  It's common to create a new thread with the 'connfd' as a parameter so that each client can be handled independently.

Read up on accept().

Comment: well i changed sockfd1 inside read() to connfd and also used fork() after accept() function...still the server doesn't output my input

Comment: Does the accept() return wehn the client connects?  What happens when you put a breakpoint on the next line?  Also, please post the relevant parts of your code inline in your question. Without that, as soon as that link goes dead, your question has 0 value for anyone.

Comment: yes the accept returns a non-negative number?...is the code working on your machine?